# I want to change the breakpoint in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The sm breakpoint in bootstrap startes from 768px. I want that to start from 710px. I notice that in bootstrap.css file , couple of places have

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
```

If I change those to 710px  , will that work... Does anyone have any experience on this
?

Answer (score 0):

Check this page for customizing bootstrap : http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

In **Media queries breakpoints**,change inputs values to those you want and then compile.

Variable is named `@screen-sm-min` , set it's value to 710px